# Angular - Routing path throwing console error

Tags: angular

I have the PostListComponent imported app.module.ts, but when I use the following line in my routes

```
  { path: '', component: PostListComponent }
```

I get the error

```
Error: Component PostListComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
```

If I remove that line then the page loads. I imported PostListComponent so I can't seem to figure out what's throwing the error.

app.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { PostCreateComponent } from './posts/post-create/post-create.component';
import { PostListComponent } from 'angular-03-finished/angular-03-finished/src/app/posts/post-list/post-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: PostListComponent },
  { path: 'create', component: PostCreateComponent }
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import {
  MatInputModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatExpansionModule
} from "@angular/material";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { PostCreateComponent } from "./posts/post-create/post-create.component";
import { HeaderComponent } from "./header/header.component";
import { PostListComponent } from "./posts/post-list/post-list.component";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PostListComponent,
    PostCreateComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    PostListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: i recommend that you restart the server and try

Comment: I tried that multiple times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside Your `app-routing.module.ts`

Change this import:

```
import { PostListComponent } from 'angular-03-finished/angular-03-finished/src/app/posts/post-list/post-list.component';
```

To this import:

```
import { PostListComponent } from "./posts/post-list/post-list.component";
```